# Missing Headers aws-amplify + angular 5.x

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm building a project using [angular 5.x](https://angular.io/) and [aws-amplify](https://github.com/aws/aws-amplify). I successfully managed to sign-up, confirm and sign-in my users via [aws-cognito](https://eu-central-1.console.aws.amazon.com/cognito/) and now, I would like to retrieve user's `jwt` to add it at requests header to perform CRUD operations on my [dynamoDb](http://aws.amazon.com/DynamoDB%E2%80%8E) collection.

Unluckily, when I try to perform such operation on dynamo I get the following error:

```
{
    "message": "Authorization header requires 'Credential' parameter. Authorization header requires 'Signature' parameter. Authorization header requires 'SignedHeaders' parameter. Authorization header requires existence of either a 'X-Amz-Date' or a 'Date' header. Authorization=xxxxx"
}
```

I get user's token using the following **Cognito.service**:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

/** rxjs **/
import { fromPromise } from 'rxjs/observable/fromPromise';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';

/** 3rd party **/
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';

@Injectable()
export class CognitoService {

    getJwtToken(): Observable<any> {
        return this.getCurrentSession()
            .switchMap((token) => {
                return of(token.getIdToken().getJwtToken());
            })
    }

    private getCurrentSession(): Observable<any> {
        return fromPromise(Auth.currentSession());
    }

}
```

That get's called by:

```
this.cognitoService.getJwtToken()
    .subscribe((token: string) => {
        this.dynamoService.get(
            'testResource?id=someValue',
            {
                Authorization: token
            }
         )
    })
```

And where **Dynamo.service** is the following:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

/** rxjs **/
import { fromPromise } from 'rxjs/observable/fromPromise';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

/** 3rd party **/
import { API } from 'aws-amplify';

/** App Environment **/
import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';

@Injectable()
export class DynamoDBService {

    apiName = environment.amplify.API.endpoints[0].name;

    get(path: string, headers: any): Observable<any> {
        return fromPromise(
            API.get(
                this.apiName,
                path,
                {
                    headers: headers
                }
            )
        );
    }
}
```

My environment looks like:

```
export const environment = {
    production: false,
    amplify: {
        Auth: {
            region: 'eu-central-1',
            identityPoolId: 'eu-central-1:xxx',
            userPoolId: 'eu-central-1_xxx',
            userPoolWebClientId: 'xxxx'
        },
        API: {
            endpoints: [
                {
                    name: "someName,
                    endpoint: "xxxxx"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
};
```

And of course, at the startup of my application I'm configuring amplify like:

```
...
/** App Environment **/
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
...
Amplify.configure(environment.amplify);
...
```

On my [api-gatway](https://aws.amazon.com/it/api-gateway/) I enabled standard `CORS`, `Authorization` Required and no `Token` validation.
I feel like I'm doing everything alright and I don't get what I'm doing wrong.

**EDIT**:

`Authorization` header gets properly set when using `API.get(...)` and passing it an header object like:

```
{
    Authorization: 'myToken'
}
```

More can be read at the following link [aws.github.io/aws-amplify](https://aws.github.io/aws-amplify/media/api_guide.html)

Any Suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find out what was causing the problem. The error was caused not by headers nor by code but by the route called. In `api-gateway`, you can define resources and methods.

I had an `api-gateway` structure like:

```
/
----testResource/
    ----/{id}
        ---- GET
```

And I was calling `testResource?id=someValue` and it was wrong. The right way to call the same resource by id is `testResource/someValue`.

For some reason, the gateway, instead of give me a sensed error, gave me:

```
{
    "message": "Authorization header requires 'Credential' parameter. Authorization header requires 'Signature' parameter. Authorization header requires 'SignedHeaders' parameter. Authorization header requires existence of either a 'X-Amz-Date' or a 'Date' header. Authorization=xxxxx"
}
```

And I tought it was caused by headers in general. For those struggling with the same problem:

- Make sure you are calling the correct route
- Make sure you are not using `AWS_IAM` Authorization but one coming from your `cognito user pool`
- Make sure to get the current `jwt` and pass it to all your `API` requests like I've shown in the code above.

Answer (score 1):

I don't get your issue so I will rely on the title of your question.

If a header is missing, it's because Angular simplifies the headers before giving your the response.

If you want to get the header and put it in your request, you will have to expose it.

This is done with the **[Access Control Expose Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers)** header.

By default, Angular only handle a couple of headers and erase the other ones. You probably didn't get your token because it was in a non exposed header.

Comment: I should edit my question. No header is missing. They get added properly by `aws-amplify API.method` by passing `{ header : someHeaderObj }`. I guess it's more related to `aws-amplify` and `aws-api-gateway`.

Comment: I still don't get your issue. Could you explain it  ,

Comment: I edited my question but my issue is very related to `aws-amplify` and `aws-api-gateway`. Essentially, no angular example is available, so I'm taking a look to the docs and examples on React projects. When I try to do any CRUD operation I get the error I mentioned even tough I'm properly adding the `Authorization` header. In github's issues has been said that adding `Authorization` header is enough even tough the error complains about other headers.

Comment: And did you try to log your headers server side and Angular side ? Are they sent, are they received ?

Comment: It's Serverless, no server side. Yes, they are getting sent and received.

Comment: Serverless for you, but you still have a server than handle your requests, and I'm pretty sure Amazon gives you a console :) So, they're sent, received, and this error stills pop. Does your server console give any more logs about that issue ?

Comment: @AndreaM16 Did you see **[this question](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=237288)** that is about the same error as yours ?

Comment: 1) Going to take a look at logs. 2) Yes, I've seen that. I have no `AWS_IAM` authorization type enabled on the API Gateway method, just standard CORS and Authorization Header required with no token validation. +1 for help.